# I want to create a command that will compute fine

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm developing a library system for my project. My adviser ask me to compute a fine for overdue books. I have 3 textboxes one for student id, book title and isbn, and I also have two datetime pickers; one is for date and one for due date. I want a create a command that will compute a fine if the borrower didn't return the book on duedate and will input the fine in my table 'Borrowbook' column 'Penalty'.

This is my code:

```
string constring = ("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [Student ID], ISBN, Title, Date, [Due Date], Penalty FROM    Borrowbook;", con);


        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable Records = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(Records);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = Records;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(Records);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (dateTimePicker2.Value < DateTime.Now)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Borrowbook (Penalty) VALUES  (@Penalty)";
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Penalty", SqlDbType.Date);
            p1.Value = 50;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
```

This code is not working but it runs properly and didn't have any errors. But I think this is the idea for my code. I put this code in the button where also my datagridview will show my data.

Comment: Where did you executes your SQL statement? Did you even use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) anywhere in your code?

Comment: And to which reader do you apply the fine?

Comment: I edit my post and now I have an error. It says 'Failed to convert parameter value from Int32 to a datetime. This error is on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't executed your query.

You need:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You will also need a `SqlConnection` object that points to the correct `SQL Server` database.

As an additional note, your database schema looks a bit fuzzy, how would you know what person incurred the penalty? You haven't inserted any other identifier, just the penalty amount.

Comment: I have sqlconnection but I didnt include it in my post.

Comment: @JonSy - okay - well you need to execute the `cmd` using what I've provided in my ansdwer.

Comment: I edit my post and now I have an error. It says 'Failed to convert parameter value from Int32 to a datetime. This error is on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Penalty", SqlDbType.Date);

Comment: Needs to be SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Penalty", SqlDbTybe.Int);

Comment: It works for me. But my  another problem is to add the penalty in specified person.

Comment: @JonSy - you've already asked a different question in the comments.  Your original problem was the query was not executing. You should accept an answer here and then make a new question for the specified person problem.